# Call MouseEventHandler from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a MouseEventHandler in Main form :

```
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Home_MouseMove);
        }

        public static void Home_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bomb.Stop();
            bomb.Start();
        }
```

How can I call the MouseEventHandler from another form?

Any other good method?

Comment: You can create an event in the other frm that triggers the mouse event handler, and why dont you use the mouse event handler on the other form, any reason for that?

Comment: Because I wrote a timer function at the main form. I don't want to rewrite the code again in other form.

Comment: Then just create an event in window 2 that the main window subscribes to

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  It is like Russia, you don't call a mouse event handler, it calls you.  Triggered by moving the mouse.  If you create another form and it has the focus then it gets the call.  You can implement IMessageFilter to get mouse messages before they are dispatched to the window with the focus.

Comment: The mouse event handler is static, it should be accessible to other form. Form2.MouseMove = MainForm.Home_MouseMove;

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you have to change Home_MouseMove event to non static:

```
public void Home_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bomb.Stop();
        bomb.Start();
    }
```

Go to program.cs file and change the code from this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmMain());
    }
}
```

to this code:

```
static class Program
{
    public static FrmMain MainForm;// add this line
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm = new FrmMain();// add this line
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

now on the form2 you can call the MouseMove in the main form like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call MouseMove event in main form
        Program.MainForm.FrmMain_MouseMove(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that. It works.
The code in main form is:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void FrmMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form1().Show();
    }
}
```

The Form1 code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.MainForm.FrmMain_MouseMove(null, null);
    }
}
```

it has one button with click event. When you click the button the mouse move event in main form is raised

Finally the program.cs code is

```
static class Program
{
    public static FrmMain MainForm;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm = new FrmMain();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it words. I can send the project if you want